# The tabhost and fragment combination transaction throw error expection in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragmenttransaction

There are a tab host in my app. it uses an fragment activities and contain 5 tabs (fragment)
In the 3rd tab , there is a button, when I click on it , it will go to another fragment, which is to replace the original fragment

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("click_button","Gallery","Gallery_select_" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()),null).build());
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("imageObj", images.get(position));
                Fragment newFragment = (Fragment) new GalleryDetail();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.tabcontent, newFragment,"gallery_detail");
                transaction.addToBackStack("gallery_detail");
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
```

Then the problem will happen in this flow:

1) open the 3rd tab

2) click on the button go to the next level fragment

3) click on the other tab e.g. 1st tab

4) return to the 3rd tab (at this time , it will in the next level fragment instead of the first level)

5) press back button

```
 02-19 02:16:46.427: E/AndroidRuntime(27697): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: PhotoGallery{43bc3500 #1 id=0x7f04003b Gallery}
```

How can I return the first level if I exit from the 3rd tab? I believe this will fix the problem ? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace `replace()` method with a pair of `add()` and `remove()` method. Or you may try to use `SupportFragmentManager`